# Can't Connect to OS X through Local IP Address

Tags: wireless-networking

I've been encountering a problem connecting to my computer for months now, and finally have enough information together that hopefully someone can help me.  I'm not sure if the problem with my laptop or my router; the laptop is a early 2010 Macbook Pro running Mavericks, and the router is one from Verizon, model name `MI424WR-GEN3I`, firmware version `40.21.10.3`.

It started out as not being able to use AirPlay from my Macbook Pro to my Apple TV -- things worked fine from my iPad, but there was always a connection error with my Macbook.  Apps that try to connect my iPad wirelessly to my Macbook over the local wifi network, like AirDisplay, all don't work.  I later realized that I couldn't VNC into my laptop.  Now, I'm trying to forward a port from my router to my laptop, and that's not working either.  I tried to ping my laptop from my router today, and none of the requests went through, so I figure that there's just something wrong with trying to connect to my laptop from the local IP address.

I'm not sure if the problem is with the router or the laptop, but maybe someone has experience this problem before.  If I start a local server on port `3000` for example, I can connect to it fine at `localhost:3000` or `127.0.0.1:3000`.  However, trying to connect to it at the local IP address, `192.168.1.16:3000` doesn't work at all.  The port that I forwarded from the router isn't working either, and trying to connect to the same port on the external IP address doesn't pass the request through to my laptop, either.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably security settings on your laptop.  Modern operating systems are not wide open like they once were.  For example, VNC (aka, Screen Sharing in OS X) is not enabled by default.  If you wanted to enable Screen Sharing, you can try this command

```
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -activate -configure -access -off -restart -agent -privs -all -allowAccessFor -allUsers
```

So you probably want to see what network ports your apps are using (with a tool like Network Utility, located in the /System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/ folder) and see if these are blocked.  You can do this from any *other* computer with a terminal command

```
telnet <your_Mac_hostname_or_IP> <port#_to_test>
```

Say you find that one app uses port 4000 and your MacBook is called MyMac.  Here's what that would look like if it failed

```
telnet MyMac 4000
Trying 192.168.1.2...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.1.2: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

But if the port is opened, you'd see a different result like this

```
telnet MyMac 4000
Trying 192.168.1.2...
Connected to MyMac.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

(At this point you can hit CTRL+] then "q" to quit telnet)

If you wanted to open a port that is not responding, you can use the `pfctl` command.  Here's a link to a good article on [using `pf` commands](http://krypted.com/mac-security/a-cheat-sheet-for-using-pf-in-os-x-lion-and-up/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much! I"ll check this stuff out and see if I can discover anything else.